# $u(x+h)-u(x)=cp(x') h$ for some $x'$ between $x, x+h$, what derivative rule is this?

Tags: derivatives

$u(x+h)-u(x)=c p(x') h$ for some $x'$ between $x, x+h$, what derivative rule is this?

$c$ is constant, $p$ is continuous function, $x,h \in \mathbb{R}$. Dividing by $h$ and taking limit $\rightarrow \infty$ one gets:

$$u'(x)=cp(x)$$

But I forgot what this idea about "for some $x'$ between $x,x+h$" is?

Comment: $x'$ is simply a point $\in (x,x+h)$ ? Is $x$ a variable $\in \mathbb R$ ? The $'$ notation is **really** misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some $u(x)$ continuous in $[x,x+h]$ and differentiable over $(x,x+h)$, by the Mean Value Theorem :

$$\exists x_0 \in (x,x+h) : u(x_0) = \frac{u(x+h)-u(x)}{h}$$

Now, for whatever reason in the statement you found, it seems that it is something like

$$u(x_0)\cdot h =  u(x+h)-u(x) \implies chp(x_0) = u(x+h)-u(x)$$

where a function $p(x)$ such that $u(x_0) = cp(x_0)$ is used.

Without any further context though, it's hard to understand the intuition behind this.

Comment: I think this seems reasonable. However the intuition as to why they use $x'$ was not that intuitive. It seems that what they really want to approximate is $p$, rather than $u$.